# flask route function injects "None" into url and makes two GET requests

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, backend

this is a bit of a weird one, I have a routing function `profile` that takes the username from the url and redirects to the profile of that user -

```
@app.route('/profiles/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def profile(username):
    if username == "None":
        print("wtf")
    print(username + "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    visited_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if visited_user:
        return render_template('profile.html', visited_user=visited_user)
    else:
        return abort(404)
`
```

and as you can tell by my creative attempts at debugging, the terminal should log a "wtf" message if the username is None, not null, just a "None" string. and it does, at its second GET request, which it shouldn't be able to do in the first place.
here's the terminal after entering the url 
"http://localhost:5000/profiles/a"

```
a<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2018 11:38:56] "GET /profiles/a HTTP/1.1" 200 -
wtf
None<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2018 11:38:56] "GET /profiles/None HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Did the first request end up in `if visited_user` or in `else`? In case of former, there is probably something in `profile.html` that redirected the browser back to `/profiles/None`. If latter, then the 404 page is configured to redirect to `/profiles/None`.

Comment: @zvone first request ends up in `if visited_user`, in the second one it ends up in the `else`

Answer (score 0):

problem located
I had a `onerror` attribute inside an img tag which refreshed the page to update the img source